# nyc Unable to lookup source > ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: cypress, code-coverage, nyc

I am having trouble with generating nyc reports in gitlab ci... I am trying to run a cypress script to test my website, but the reports are not generated properly. The coverage gets updated fine but I can not open the files in the gitlab ci artifacts.

I have just found out that it does not work either in my local env. How can I fix that so that the reports would work properly and point to the proper files in both environments?

This is the .nycrc file...

```
{
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.js"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "cypress/"
    ],
    "reporter": [
        "lcov",
        "text-summary"
    ],
    "all": true,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "instrument": false
}
```

I have experimented with the "all" value and I need the files on the image to be the files that have the proper coverage and I can go through them....

I am now trying to figure out how to fix the correct source maps... but I cant make it work properly with the source maps.. anyone has any suggestions?

[image: index.html]